# Issues with bypassing internet filter by using squid proxy on Azure VM

Tags: http, azure, proxy, firewall, squid

Hey I'm trying to bypass my college internet filter by my own proxy server hosted on Microsoft azure VM.Its an Ubuntu VM and the proxy software used is squid.
The tutorial i have followed is
http://www.jittuu.com/2014/5/29/how-to-setup-squid-as-forward-proxy-in-azure/

I use SwitchySharp(a chrome app) to connect to my proxy server

The issue I'm facing is that the internet connection which I would like to bypass doesn't allow me to connect to the proxy server.It works fine with other internet connections.
What might be the problem?
Any input is appreciated thank you.

Comment: What surprises you? The idea of firewall is to prevent your access to certain websites - know proxy servers are among them (so expect these to banned). Also IT team of your college could have banned your ability to change a proxy sever at all

Comment: Whether you agree with the morality of his inquiry, I think it's still a reasonable question.

George, you will probably have an easier time if you use a VPN or something like [nomachine](https://www.nomachine.com).  If you continue to pursue the proxy server route: a common tactic in these situations is to change the listening port to a common protocol port that isn't blocked (eg, 80).  You may be able to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

First of all just try to ping the public public IP of the azure virtual machine that you used to host squid proxy server and see whether it works or not.

*> The issue I'm facing is that the internet connection which I would like to bypass doesn't allow me to connect to the proxy server.It works fine with other internet connections. What might be the problem?*

Even if you change the system proxy setting to use the azure virtual machine, the traffic hitting the standard ports (80,443) of the Ethernet interface card will be configured to redirect to your college filtering app.

SwitchySharp will help you to switch the upstream proxy but the traffic will be routed only through your college server